# rspec shared_examples cannot be nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to write two tests and both partially rely on the same behavior, approximately as seen below. This is something I would like to pull out of my code, and it seems like shared contexts are how to do it, but there is a scoping problem.

```
require 'spec_helper'
def getlink()
  ['link','id']
end
describe 'static pages' do
  hash = {'link' => {'id' => 'payload'},'link_' => {'id_' => 'payload_'}}
  subject{hash}
  shared_examples_for 'it is mapped correctly' do |link, id|
    it 'is mapped correctly' do
      expect(subject[link]).to have_key(id)
    end
  end
  describe 'the payload is correct' do
    it_should_behave_like 'it is mapped correctly', 'link','id'
    it 'has the correct value' do
      expect(subject['link']['id']).to eq('payload')
    end
  end
  # works fine
  describe 'the get link function works correctly' do
    it 'links inside the has' do
      link = getlink()
      expect(subject[link[0]]).to have_key(link[1])
    end
  end
  # fails saying that it_should_behave_like is not defined.
  describe 'the get link function works correctly with shared examples' do
    it 'links inside the has' do
      link = getlink()
      it_should_behave_like 'it is mapped correctly', link[0], link[1]
    end
  end
end
```

why is this designed to fail? Is there an idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Like other `it` methods, `it_should_behave_like` is not defined within other `it` methods. You can see that you get the same exception when nesting regular `it`s:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
describe 'it inside it' do
  it 'outer' do
    it 'inner' do
    end
  end
end
#=>  1) it inside it outer
#=>     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
#=>     NoMethodError:
#=>       undefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x28e1e60>
#=>     # stuff.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

To fix the exception, you could simply get rid of the outer `it`:

```
describe 'the get link function works correctly with shared examples' do
  link = getlink()
  it_should_behave_like 'it is mapped correctly', link[0], link[1]
end
```

If the outer `it` is being used to describe some information, you could make it a `context` instead:

```
describe 'the get link function works correctly with shared examples' do
  context 'links inside the has' do
    link = getlink()
    it_should_behave_like 'it is mapped correctly', link[0], link[1]
  end
end
```